# Using event driven input detection in LIBGDX for moving actors

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having trouble with event driven input detection for moving my actors.

I'm currently using a `GestureDetector` and detecting a Tap (this all works)`

```
@Override
 public void show() {
    GestureDetector GD = new GestureDetector(this);
    InputMultiplexer inputMulti = new InputMultiplexer();
    inputMulti.addProcessor(hudStage);
    inputMulti.addProcessor(GD); 
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMulti);
}

@Override
public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    System.out.println("YOU HAVE PERFORMED A TAP"); 
    this.playStage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    return true;
}`
```

Currently tap just prints out something along the lines of you have performed a tap(see above) it also calls the stage act method which works partly (It moves the actor a frames worth of movement instead of the entire distance). I've used polling to get the actor to perform how I want as i can call the method in the render loop which then allows it to continue updating movements frame by frame. Using Event driven I've not currently found a  of updating it frame by frame so instead it does as much as it can in one frame and then stops.

I've looked around, a lot, looked into threading but it seems libgdx is not thread safe. My main problem with going back to polling is that i need to separate out my stages and I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

For polling i didn't use an action but used this code

```
if(!fStarted){            
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            fStarted = true;
            touchX = Gdx.input.getX();
            spriteX = cSprite.x;            
        }
        }
        final float dv = delta * speed;
        if (Math.abs(touchX - spriteX) > 45) {
            playStage.getBatch().draw(flameImage, spriteX, fSprite.y);
            if (spriteX < touchX) {
                spriteX += dv;
                //fSprite.x = spriteX;
            }
            if (spriteX > touchX) {
                spriteX -= dv;
                //fSprite.x = spriteX;
            }
        }
        else{
            spriteX = 9000;
            fStarted=false;
        }
```

`fStarted` just determines whether or not the actor is currently moving to a position. As the actor is a projectile I didn't want more than one at one point (game choices you know).

If there is any other information you need just comment and I'll provide it.

**Clarity**
How can I use event driven gesture detection to move an actor to a position that is tapped by the user?

Comment: If I did not missunderstand your question, you could add `MoveTo`-Action to your `Actor` inside the `tap` method. Example: `myActor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(x, y, duration))`, where x and y is the tap-position (you may have to project it to the world) and duration is the time it should take to move the `Actor` there.

Comment: @springrbua that poses the same problem it'll only perform the move to for one frames worth of movement updating. Currently I've just gone with an imperfect workaround that I'm calling a design choice.

Comment: I have read your question again and as much as i understood, you want to call `stage.act` only, when you are touching the screen. Is that right?

Comment: @Springrbua So the tap event is triggered when a finger touches down and then up i.e taps the screen (the finger must stay within a certain radius of the initial touch down to count as a tap). So when a tap occurs I want to move the projectile from a point a to point b (where the user has tapped). I'm having no trouble making the actor perform the action the problem is the actor only moves a frames worth of distance as I can repeatedly update the position like you would when polling for input in the render loop

Comment: okay, so you want to move the `Actor` to the tappoint, and update it's movement as long as he did not reach the tappoint right? Then you can do that with the `moveTo` action and call `stage.act(delta)` in the render method. If you want to update the `stage` only when an event occures and then only as long as something is moving, you might want to take a look at `noncontinuous rendering` (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering)